# Cannot start new line with "\n"?

Tags: java, string, tostring, arrays

I am working on a project and there is a small part of it really confusing me.
Say I have a String array :

```
String[]text = {"string","array"};
```

for example.

And I want to make it to a single String with a new line "\n" between every single word.

So here is my code

```
public String setText(String [] text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    if (text.length > 0) {
        result.append(text[0]);
        for (int i=1; i<text.length; i++) {
            result.append(newline);
            result.append(text[i]);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

My code doesnt work. The return value is a single string but when I use it, it is still in one line.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you

Allan

Comment: Your code *does* work in that it will include the system default line separator. How that is *used* is a different matter. What are you trying to do with the result?

Comment: The key thing missing from your question is: **How** are you using the resulting string? For instance, if you're outputting it to (say) an HTML stream, newlines don't cause line breaks in HTML (that's what paragraphs, and/or the `<br>` tag, are for).

Comment: You're using the system line separator, which is good practice. But if the OS you're checking the result on differs from the one running the JVM, that might not work. Like the other commenters said, we'll need to know how you're using that String. Output to stdout? Output to file? Do you use streams or writers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see what `System.getProperty("line.separator");` returns?
In different OS it will be different symbols `\n` - Linux and `\r\n` in Windows
Try to use
    `System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");` or `System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you use the result. Have you tried writing it to System.out / a file or anything similar?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) from Google's [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com).

`Joiner.on(System.getProperty("line.separator")).join(text)`

Comment: Interesting, but irrelevant to the question. The code is clearly succeeding in adding the newlines.